# TAR: multiple directories in a bash script

Tags: cron, directory, tar

I am trying to TAR files within 5 different directories that are less than 7 days old.

Using the find command, I can find the files that I need to TAR after I use this:

```
find /opt/splunk/var/lib/splunk/firewall/db/ -type f -mtime -7
find /opt/splunk/var/lib/splunk/cb/db/ -type f -mtime -7
find /opt/splunk/etc -type f -mtime -7
find /opt/splunk/var/lib/splunk/cb/db/ -type f -mtime -7
find /opt/splunk/var/lib/wineventlog/db -type f -mtime -7
```

And I can find multiple files that need to be backed up within these 5 directories.

How do I TAR these files that I found using the find command, and make sure it ONLY grabs the files that are 7 days old? After doing this, I would like to TAR them up into one big file, and rsync them to a remote server.

Here is a script I currently ran on a weekly cron, but it is a bit too much as we only need files that are 7 days old in these directories.

```
#!/bin/bash
name=$(date '+%y-%m-%d')
tar -zcf /opt/splunk/var/backups/splunkbackup$(date '+%y-%m-%d').tar.gz 
/opt/splunk/etc /opt/splunk/var/lib/splunk/firewall 
/opt/splunk/var/lib/splunk/ossec /opt/splunk/var/lib/wineventlog 
/opt/splunk/var/lib/cb
rsync -avz --remove-source-files /opt/splunk/var/backups/splunkbackup* 
svc_splkbup@HOST:/var/log/splunk/backups/indexer
```

Answer (score 1):

as per `man tar` use `-T` or `-N`

### -T

```
 find ... | tar czf XXX.tgz -T -
```

where

- `...` is your `find` options
- `XXX.tgz` your tar file
- `-T` - instruct tar to read file to be tared from stdin

### −N

`-N`, `--newer` can also be used, you first have to generate a 7 days old file or date (`touch -7 days` or `date -7 days`)

```
 tar -czf XXX.tgz -N ref /opt/splunk/{etc,var/lib,var/lib/w}
```

where

- `ref` is your ref file or date
- `/opt/splunk/{etc,var/lib,var/lib/w}` will expand to `/opt/splunk/etc /opt/splunk/var/lib /opt/splunk/var/lib/w`
- note that there is no `find`

Comment: Depending on which tar implementation you are using, the option `-T` either enables to use `$TAPE` as archive output file, or enables trusted extensions.

Answer (score -1):

Is you use the right tar implementation, this is simple:

```
star -c -f out.tar -find /opt/splunk/etc -type f -mtime -7
```

You of course may add more directory names after the `-find` argument.

This is much faster than using `find` in a separate process, since the `stat(2)` calls done inside `libfind` are used by the `star` code and there is no need to do this a second time.